# How to Store RichTextBox Content to SQLServer Database in WPF using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, richtextbox

I'm experiencing a very frustrating issue storing a `RichTextBox` with formatting to my database using entity framework.

Here is my code:

```C#
namespace simpleton
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for AddNewOE.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class AddNewOE : Window
    {
        //db connection
        simpletonDBEntities _db = new simpletonDBEntities();

      public AddNewOE()
      {
        InitializeComponent();
      }

       private void insertobBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
          db_entry newdb_entries = new db_entry()
          {
            ReportDetails = ConvertRtbToBytes(rtfText)
          };

          _db.ob_entries.Add(newOb_entries);
          _db.SaveChanges();  
       }

        public static byte[] ConvertRtbToBytes(string richTextBox)
        {
          byte[] data = null;
          string rtfText; //string to save to db
          TextRange tr = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
          using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
          {
            tr.Save(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);
            rtfText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray());
          }
          return data;
        }

    }
}
```

I'm getting the error on the `ConvertRtbToBytes()` function:

> 'string' does not contain definition for 'Document' and no accessible extension method 'Document' accepting a first argument of type string could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am also sure the general code is not Okay.

Comment: Just advising: Here at SO you don't change the title to "SOLVED", you mark an answer as accepted.

Comment: Noted, with thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be more careful with your problem description, because I doubt that you want to store a RichTextBox in the database. I'm guessing you want to store the **content** of a RichTextBox in the database.

The error itself is pretty self-explanatory:

> 'string' does not contain definition for 'Document' and no accessible extension method 'Document' accepting a first argument of type string could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

You have a parameter named `richTextBox` of type `string`, which you later try to use in this way:

```
public static byte[] ConvertRtbToBytes(string richTextBox)
{
    // ...
    TextRange tr = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
    // ...
}
```

So you are trying to access the `Document` property of a `string`, but `string` does not have a `Document` property. You probably meant to make the parameter of type `RichTextBox`.

That being said, your code has many more flaws and won't even compile:

In method `insertobBtn_Click`:

- `rtfText` is used, but never defined
- You create a variable named `newdb_entries`, but try to save one named `newOb_entries`

In method `ConvertRtbToBytes`:

- You declare `byte[] data = null;` and return `data`, but `data` is never set or filled with data
- You define `rtfText` and assign some value to it, but don't do anything with it

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out...

```c#
namespace simpleton
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for AddNewOE.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class AddNewOE : Window
    {

        //db connection
      simpletonDBEntities _db = new simpletonDBEntities();

      public AddNewOE()
      {
        InitializeComponent();
      }

       private void insertobBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       { 
          TextRange tr = new TextRange(rtbEditor.Document.ContentStart, rtbEditor.Document.ContentEnd);
          MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
          tr.Save(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);
          string rtfText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray());

          db_entry newdb_entries = new db_entry()
          {
            ReportDetails = rtfText

          };

          _db.ob_entries.Add(newOb_entries);
          _db.SaveChanges();  
       }



    }
```